# Plotting inequalities yields undesired kink using RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I would like to plot two inequalities being satisfied.

Plotting them both separately yields

```
d = 1;
L = 0.5;

RegionPlot[{y > x + d + L, y > -x + 2*d + L}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, 0, 
  15}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

However, if I want to plot both inequalities being satisfied, i.e.

```
RegionPlot[{y > x + d + L && y > -x + 2*d + L}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, 0, 
  15}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

I get[image]

where there is now an unexpected kink at the bottom - why is that the case?

Comment: Request more `PlotPoints` until you are satisfied with the result. For instance `PlotPoints -> 60` seems to remove the artifact.

Answer (score 1):

- When we use the code

```
d = 1;
L = 0.5;
RegionPlot[{y > x + d + L, y > -x + 2*d + L}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, 0, 
  15}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

It only draw two opacity region and overlay them. We can double click the output and move one of them,it indicate that it doesn't real calculate the intersection of the two regions.

[image]

- For this case,inceasing the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` work.

```
RegionPlot[{y > x + d + L && y > -x + 2*d + L}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, 0, 
  15}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

- Some times we prefer to use `Region` or `DiscretizeRegion`.

```
d = 1;
L = 0.5;
reg = ImplicitRegion[{y > x + d + L, 
    y > -x + 2*d + L}, {{x, -15, 15}, {y, 0, 15}}];
Region[Style[reg, Blue], Frame -> True]
```

[image]